# Reduce kivy button text width to fit button passively

Tags: python, kivy

I want to adjust the size of the text in my button so that the button.texture_size[0] is just less than the button.width.

My app uses a font_size for these buttons that mostly fits fine. But in some cases, I have longer text and I would like to passively fit the text to the button. In these specific cases, I would like to reduce the font_size from this “standard” size I have for all buttons to something that will fit in the button.

I can make an if statement that is attached to a button that every time I press will reduce the size of the button. Then when the texture_size[0]< btn.width it stops reducing the font_size.

```py
  def manual_resize(self):
    if self.btn01.texture_size[0]>self.btn01.width:
      self.btn01.font_size-=1
```

This works nicely but I need to manually press a button.

If I try to replace this with an automated process in a while loop the texture_size[0] never changes. Specifically what I did was attach the method below to the on_size method of the parent widget. Unfortunately this just loops forever, never changing the texture_size.

```py
  def auto_resize(self,*args):
    while self.btn01.texture_size[0]>self.btn01.width:
      self.btn01.font_size-=1
```

In the past I’ve been able to use Clock.schedule_once() to let the texture_size settle into its value. Is there a way I can do that here or may some other approach?

Here is an example of the two approaches:

```py
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout

from kivy.clock import Clock

KV='''
BaseContainer:
  anchor: anchor
  btn01: btn01
  # btn02: btn02
  anchor_x: 'center'
  anchor_y: 'center'
  canvas.before:
    Color:
      rgb: [200/255,100/255,100/255]
    Rectangle:
      pos: self.pos
      size: self.size
  BoxLayout:
    orientation:"vertical"
    AnchorLayout:
      id:anchor
      BoxLayout:
        size_hint:None,None
        size:btn01.width, btn01.height
        Button:
          id:btn01
          text:"press me"
    BoxLayout:
      Button:
        text:"resize"
        on_press:
          # root.resize_guy()
          root.manual_resize()
'''

class BaseContainer(Screen):
  def __init__(self,**kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)

  def on_size(self,*args):
    print('BaseContainer on_size')
    self.btn01.font_size=40
    self.btn01.size=(100,100)
    self.count=0


    # Clock.schedule_once(self.auto_resize, .01)
    #uncomment here to see the passive attempt that doesn't quite work

  def auto_resize(self,*args):
    print('BaseContainer auto_resize')
    while self.btn01.texture_size[0]>self.btn01.width:
      print('self.btn01.texture_size[0]::', self.btn01.texture_size[0])
      print('self.btn01.width::', self.btn01.width)
      self.btn01.font_size-=1
      self.count+=1
      if self.count>20:
        break

  def manual_resize(self):
    if self.btn01.texture_size[0]>self.btn01.width:
      print('self.btn01.texture_size[0]::', self.btn01.texture_size[0])
      print('self.btn01.width::', self.btn01.width)
      print('self.btn01.text_size::', self.btn01.text_size)
      print('self.btn01.font_size::', self.btn01.font_size)
      self.btn01.font_size-=1



class MainApp(MDApp):
  def __init__(self,**kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
    print('MainApp __init__')

  def build(self):
    # return Builder.load_file('button_example.kv')
    return Builder.load_string(KV)

if __name__=='__main__':
  MainApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out kivy was prepared for my issue. I just need to add the method `self.btn01.texture_update()`
Here's what it looks like in my example above:

```py
  def auto_resize(self,*args):
    print('BaseContainer auto_resize')
    while self.btn01.texture_size[0]>self.btn01.width:
      print('self.btn01.texture_size[0]::', self.btn01.texture_size[0])
      print('self.btn01.width::', self.btn01.width)
      self.btn01.font_size-=1
      self.btn01.texture_update()# <--- this updates the texture_size
```

Thank you pcrafter for solution!